# Keyboard Shortcut to open multiple terminals in vscode without splitting the screen

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, keyboard-shortcuts

I want to open multiple terminals in VS Code (horizontally), but I don't want to split the existing terminal that I already opened with 'Ctrl' + `.

I can go to the integrated terminal and click on the '+' icon, but I'm not sure how to do the same via keyboard shortcut?

Comment: what are you currently using that causes the "screen to split"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Keyboard shortcut for it is

> `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `

**Multiple Workspaces:**

If you have opened multiple workspaces in Vscode, then, this keyboard shortcut will ask which workspace to use to open the new terminal in.

It will add a new Terminal to the Terminal Sidebar Tray and will not split the terminal anymore.

Answer (score 0):

See the commands in the [command palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette) whose names start with `Terminal: Create New Terminal`. For example, the basic `Terminal: Create New Terminal` command is bound to <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd>. You can bind other similar commands by editing your [keyboard shortcuts](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings).